# Is it possible to install Raspbian on raspberry PI without keyboard?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

So far, what i tried is that

1. put raspbian image on to SD card.
2. power up PI with Sd card.

And after booting, a set-up option window popped up which i can't skip without keyboard.
**Is there any way to skip this option menu ..?**

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

No, there are no buttons or physical input on the Raspberry PI itself, so without plugging some input device in you cannot skip the menu.

You could install Raspbian on a Raspberry PI emulator, do all the setup on your computer, then copy the already-setup disc image to your SD card. Here's a tutorial for setting up QEMU to emulate the Raspberry PI (and it includes installing Raspbian on the emulator): http://xecdesign.com/qemu-emulating-raspberry-pi-the-easy-way/

That seems like a lot of work though. You should probably just borrow someone's keyboard.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Btw, I am wondering if there is a way to find out which source file or script is in charge of prompting the Config-menu at boot?

Comment: You could search the Raspbian sources for a word or phrase that appears in that menu.